# Mocking multiple resttemplate in a single test method using mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I needed to write test case for a method which is having multiple `resttemplate.getForObject()` call with different response type. So I wrote like this:

```
@Test
public void tempMethodTest(){
    doReturn(abc).when(restTemplate).getForObject(anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.<Class<ABC>>any());//1st rest call
    doReturn(def).when(restTemplate).getForObject(anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.<Class<DEF>>any());//2nd rest call
    doReturn(efg).when(restTemplate).getForObject(anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.<Class<EFG>>any());//3rd rest call
    //when(restTemplate.getForObject(anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.<Class<ABC>>any())).thenReturn(abc);
    //when(restTemplate.getForObject(anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.<Class<DEF>>any())).thenReturn(def);
    //when(restTemplate.getForObject(anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.<Class<EFG>>any())).thenReturn(efg);

    assertNotNull(service.tempMethod(obj));
}
```

But while testing, I am getting below provided exception during first REST call:

```
com.example.EFG cannot be cast to com.example.ABC
```

Answer (score 0):

So finally I found solution to this problem.

```
@Test
public void getBaseStationConfigurationTest(){
    when(restTemplate.getForObject(anyString(), any())).thenReturn(abc,def,efg);
    assertNotNull(service.tempMethod(obj));
}
```

Comment: how to do if it is postForEntity() with two different rest template calls?